# Timeout for webdriver.PhantomJS in python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I just use selenium-python.

When I use `webdriver.Firefox()`, I can get the result.
When I use `webdriver.PhantomJS()`, the result can't be returned (the script is hanging).

Can anyone help me?

```
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='./lib/phantomjs/phantomjs')
url = "http://aminer.org/search/jie%20tang"
browser.get(url)
```

Comment: Do you understand what `PhantomJS` is? It does the operation without a visible browser output. Try using a `Chrome` driver instead.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi what does this have to do with the question? Even if it is headless, it is still a browser.

Comment: He says *get the result*. I have no idea what that means, but he says it works for Firefox.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi I see what you mean. The OP means that it would just hang forever in case of PhantomJS (reproduce the problem and looking for a workaround). Thanks!

Comment: @MalikBrahimi  what I mean get result is I can get the result of      browser.page_source.encode('utf-8')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reproduced the issue and see hanging PhantomJS too. I've tried multiple workarounds (including loading the "https" url with disabled web security; try not to load images, increase the script and page load timeouts, update phantomjs etc), but haven't made it work till the moment.

There is an alternative approach here that doesn't involve selenium - *use the AMiner API*.

Here is how you can get the same search results using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/):

```
import requests


url = 'http://storeland.ru/user/login'
api_url = 'https://api.aminer.org/api/search/people'
with requests.Session() as session:
    session.get(url)

    params = {
        'query': 'jie+tang',
        'size': '20',
        'sort': 'relevance',
        # 'offset': 20  # set offset for pagination
    }
    response = session.get(api_url, params=params)
    for item in response.json()['result']:
        print item['name']
```

Prints (the first page of search results):

```
Zhu Jie-Tang
Jie-Tang Zhao
...
Jie-Tang Wu
Tian Jietang
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just tried several ways but still can't find the answer. Aminer API is a better way. Thank you ~